# How to pass a generic type T as parameter of the instance of an Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an adapter that I would like to pass two different adapter classes and I want to pass T as a generic parameter in which I can pass every Adapter that I want, how I can accomplish this ?

```
class BaseGridConcatAdapter(private val context: Context, private val myRandomAdapters: MyCustomAdapter,private val spanCount:Int) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseConcatHolder<*>>() {

...

}
```

Later in the code I use this bind

```
inner class BaseConcatViewHolder(itemView: View): BaseConcatHolder<MyCustomAdapter>(itemView){
        override fun bind(adapter: MyCustomAdapter) {
            itemView.rv_test_concat.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
```

in which I plan to pass the same adapter as I passed as the cosnstructor, but that adapter could be any adapter

How do I do this ? I'm new at generics

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got it, but is this what you were looking for?

```
    class A<T>(private val theParam: T) {
        inner class B(private val theInnerParam: T) {

        }
    }
```

The use would be like this:

```
val theA: A<String> = A("hello world")
```